# Count number of string in a result array

Tags: php

how can I count, using PHP, number of "rep_onoff" that has value "SI",  resulted from an array like the following?

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
         [0] => NO [rep_onoff] => NO )
         [1] => Array ( [0] => SI [rep_onoff] => SI
         [2] => Array ( [0] => SI [rep_onoff] => SI )
         [3] => Array ( [0] => SI [rep_onoff] => SI )
         [4] => )
```

regards

Comment: Iterate recursively over the array.

Comment: Take look at [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function

Comment: Thank you  Pavel Janicek; i read about it but i 'am pretty new in PHP world and I cannot understand it. Can you please show me an example? If you can, obviously

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have duplicate data, Assuming you can transform your array to something like this:

```
array(
[0]=>'SI',
[1]=>'SI',
[2]=>'NO',
[3]=>'SI',
[4]=>'SI',
);
```

Solution 1:
You can use `array_count_values()`.

```
$array = array([0]=>'SI', [1]=>'SI', [2]=>'NO', [3]=>'SI', [4]=>'SI',);
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

This will output something like this:

```
Array
(
    [SI] => 4
    [NO] => 1
)
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Solution 2:

If you can't change your data, you can use `array_map()`.

```
function array_count_values_rep($arr)
{
    return $arr['rep_onoff'];
}

$arr = array(
    array(
        0 => 'NO',
        'rep_onoff' => 'NO',
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'SI',
        'rep_onoff' => 'SI',
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'SI',
        'rep_onoff' => 'SI',
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'SI',
        'rep_onoff' => 'SI',
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'NO',
        'rep_onoff' => 'NO',
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'SI',
        'rep_onoff' => 'SI',
    ),
    array(
        0 => 'SI',
        'rep_onoff' => 'SI',
    ),
);
$result = array_map('array_count_values_rep', $arr);
print_r(array_count_values($result));
```

Which will output:

```
Array ( [NO] => 2 [SI] => 5 )
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Seams Solution 2 does the job but i always get following error from log: "PHP Warning:  array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!". Can I ignore it?